# how to subscribe event raised from an object in a list of object

Tags: c#, events

I want to build a list of an object. An object in the list will raise an event that this object should be removed from the list. How can I build this mechanism? Is that kind of mechanism logic?

```
public class object()
{
   public event EventHandler listEmpty;
   List<string> name;
   ...

   public void Delete(string n)
   {
      name.Remove(n);
       ...

      if(name.isEmpty())
         //raise an event hier..
   }
}

public class MyClass
{
   public List<object> ObjList = new List<object>();

   public Remove(string x)
   {
      ObjList[5].Delete(x);
   }

    private void OnListIsEmpty(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
       ObjList.RemoveAt(5);
    }

    public MyClass()
    {
       // how to subscribe this event??
    }
}
```

Comment: `object` is a c# keyword. If you are going to anonymize your classes, at least consider using names that compile

Comment: sorry for that not compilable code. I wrote the code while I was writing the question. Actually, I would prefer to get a question based comments

Comment: Try to write some (real) code and compile that, and see what happens. Then ask questions about what doesn't work. People probably won't write the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think `ObservableCollection` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` fit your requirement.
See the following example.

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Model(string val)
    {
        Value = val;
    }

    string Value { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ObservableCollection<Model> collection = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
    collection.Add(new Model("item1"));
    collection.Add(new Model("item2"));
    collection.Add(new Model("item3"));
    collection.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            var removedItems = e.OldItems; // put a breakpoint here to observe
        }
    };

    collection.RemoveAt(1);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```